# How to handle two git repos that import the same submodule and that submodule needs to be the same version on each?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Currently I am developing on two different repos, we'll call them A and B.

Each of these repos imports a shared submodule I'll refer to as C.

Now given the relationship of repos A and B, they both require the same version of repo C, meaning that anytime I need to change repo C (to fit new features on either A or B), I need to create a pull request including that change for both repo A and B.

Making this "double pull-request" is slowing down development and so I'm curious if anyone has solved this sort of problem before.

Is there anyway to reorganize the repos so that this issue no longer arises?

I considered breaking up C into two different repos but that breaks the condition that the version of C is always the same for A and B.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: Does this mean the code for C is duplicated in the repos of both A and B? In that case you should definitely hold C in a separate repo and simply annotate it as a dependency in both A and B, leaving it to the developer to pull the latest version of C, treating it as any other dependency (just one that the dev should always ensure is up-to-date).

Comment: It already lives in its own repo and is imported as a submodule within A and B. It's just the issue of a new feature in A or B requiring a change in C which results in a pull request in C and pull requests in A and B (both of which can't be approved until the pull request in C is merged).

Comment: Sounds like there is some tight coupling going on. Intuitively I would guess the best solution would be to make the code itself less coupled, if that's at all possible.

Comment: After your comment, I looked up coupling and learned about the different types of coupling software modules can experience. Unfortunately, it seems A and B suffer from external coupling because they share a communication protocol that is defined in C (hence why they both import it). Unfortunately I don't see anyway to uncouple these given that they both need access to that communication protocol to communicate with one another. I appreciate you leading me to the concept of coupling though! @theberzi

Comment: Shot in the dark: look up the concept of *dependency injection* and consider if the code could be refactored to leverage it. If you can make C into a separate component, then you could develop it separately and ensure on A's and B's side that the version of C is up to date, and if not, automatically update it.